# can I centrlize session handling on the file system

Tags: php, apache, session, php-5.5, apache2.2

I have several web servers behind a load balancer.
Can I mount file server on all three web servers and use that mounted directory as the session folder, hence achieving centralized session management for all my web servers?
I know that technically, this can be done, what I do not know if there are any pitfalls I am not aware of. Is there a better way to centralize a session on the file system **(can not use Redis/Memcached/MySql etc)**.

**Explanation why not Memory** or other DB/Server based solution. I have tried most of those. I have a weird locking/race condition bug in one of my core systems, when using those solutions. Until I figure out this bug, I need a quick and (not necessarily) dirty solution, on the file system, where I know for sure I have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a memcached cluster as a session handler for all your web servers.
You won't need to have sticky session.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-php-sessions-on-multiple-memcached-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04

In case you want persistent of the session I would use a couchbase cluster using memcached bucket.

http://nitschinger.at/How-to-store-PHP-sessions-in-Couchbase/

Edit: You can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php
Regards,

Comment: I have locking issues with those solutions, and until I figure out this bug in my system I need quick and ( maybe) dirty solution on the file system, which has very good locking algoritems, and besides, the question is about the file system, not about alternate solutions.

Comment: Which of them solution did you tried and which issues did you find? I think you will have the same issue using disk or maybe worse as it would be more slow...

Comment: I do not have the issue on disk, I have only when I use any of the above suggested solution. It is something in my app, and it will take a long time to debug this. I need an intermidiate solution until I do. I need to know if there are any pitfalls to file system, I know how to implement the solutions u suggested.

Comment: You hava an edit with something you can try to save the session to disk.